# Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int **seqList, n, q;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
    seqList = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    int *l_sub_seq = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));//length of subsequences of all sequences                                              
    int lastAnswer = 0;

    while(q--)
    {
        int type, x, y, i;
        scanf("%d %d %d", &type, &x, &y);
        i = (x^lastAnswer) % n;
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
            l_sub_seq[i]++;
            seqList[i] = (int*)realloc(seqList[i], sizeof(int)*l_sub_seq[i]);
            seqList[i][l_sub_seq[i] - 1] = y;
            break;

            case 2:
            lastAnswer = seqList[i][y%l_sub_seq[i]];
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(seqList[i]);
    free(seqList);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(l_sub_seq);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler message:**

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2
>  Reading symbols from
>   Solution...done.
>  [New LWP 335079]
>  [Thread debugging using
>   libthread_db enabled]
>  Using host libthread_db library
>   "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>  Core was generated by
>   `./Solution'.
>  Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>   *#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50*

Comment: @WhozCriag I would be grateful If you explain this a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code potentially invokes *undefined behavior* in at least one location, and *definitely* invokes it in another.

`realloc` allows an input pointer value that is either:

1. `NULL`
2. A value returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`

Your initial allocation of `seqList` :

```
seqList = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
```

creates a sequence of pointers to int. Those pointers are *indeterminate* (they have no determined value, be it NULL or any other valid value) that can be passed to `realloc`. Therefore, later in code when you do this:

```
seqList[i] = (int*)realloc(seqList[i], sizeof(int)*l_sub_seq[i]);
here ======================^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're invoke *undefined behavior*. You can address this by ensuring your intial array contents are null-populated, either by using zero-filling `calloc` (easiest), or by loop, memset, whatever.

Later, at the end of your program, you do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(l_sub_seq);
```

That's nonsense. `l_sub_seq` was allocated with:

```
int *l_sub_seq = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

It should be free'd *once*, not in some loop, repeatedly passing the same pointer value over and over to `free`.

```
free(l_sub_seq); // no loop.
```

Whether the rest of your program "works" is up to you to decide, but the reasons for your termination woes are likely from the issues covered above.